# tensorflow copy parameters to another network(same architecture), like DQN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am implementing a Deep Q network (with fixed Q target), which requires to assign the parameters from a network to another (prediction network and target network, have the same parameter). 
I am using a convolutional network, so I use some API like:

`tf.layers.conv2d`

`tf.layers.dense` and so on.

Is there a good way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/DQN/dqn.py#L326) (line 326) is the line of code that does exactly that in this existing tensorflow-based DQN implementation. The function that it calls starts on [line 150](https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/DQN/dqn.py#L150). Does that example help?

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me ! thank you!